# Using Palatino and Euler Math

Tags: fonts, preamble

I'm using Palatino font for my thesis calling in the preamble

```
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}  

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
```

To use `eulervm` which is the correct way to call it? Before `fontenc` or after?

Comment: If you want to use `palatino` with `eulervm` you should use `\usepackage{palatino,eulervm}`, not `\usepackage{mathpazo}`.

Comment: are your sure? I have found this: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/palatino/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `mathpazo` use Palatino for the text and the Pazo fonts for math, which a common combination. The math example on the site you're referring to, do not look like `eulervm`, do it?

Comment: yeah...you convinced me...

Comment: You could also use [TeX Gyre Pagella](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgpagella/): `\usepackage{tgpagella,eulervm}`.

Answer (score 23):

By loading only `palatino` you lose the true small caps font provided by `mathpazo` and also the possibility of using old style figures.

So

```
\usepackage{mathpazo} % add possibly `sc` and `osf` options
\usepackage{eulervm}
```

is the best option.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2018, you have several options.

### With a Modern Toolchain

First, if you are able to use XeLaTex or LuaLaTeX, [there is an OpenType version of Euler out there.](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf) It is incomplete and unmaintained, but usable with care.  It is a good idea to load another math font based on Palatino, such as Asana Math, then load the symbols you want from Neo Euler over that.  Then, any symbols missing from Neo Euler, or that look too idiosyncratic for you, will get loaded from your fallback font instead.

Here is an example that sets the Euler identities in ISO style, using free clones of Palatino and AMS Euler.  In particular, the symbolic constants i, e and π are set upright in Neo Euler, and everything else is set in a clone of Palatino, including the digits and the operators sin and cos.  All math symbols are from Asana Math, which is based on pxfonts by Young Ryu, and the variable *x* is italic.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[
  Scale=1.0,
  Ligatures={Common, Discretionary, TeX}]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    cal, bfcal, frak, bffrak},
              script-features={},
              sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}

\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}
\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: The Euler Identities in Neo Euler]

Most people who want to use Euler math letters want to use them by default, though. In that case, you want to `\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}` instead, and declare your vectors as `\symbfup`.  The Palatino italics are still available as `\symit{}` or `\mathit{}`.

A good sans-serif font matching Palatino and Euler is Optima (which has a free clone, URW Classico).  A humanist monospace font that goes well with it is Inconsolata.

You can use more of Neo Euler and less of Asana Math by expanding the `range=` statement.  For the record, the complete set of symbols the font contains is:

```
\setmathfont[range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
                    "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
                    "00D7,"00F7,
                    "0131,
                    "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
                    "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
                    "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
                    "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
                    "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
                    "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
                    "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
                    "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
                    "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
                    "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
                    "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
                    "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
                    "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
                    "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
                    "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
                    "23DC-"23DF,
                    "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
                    "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
                    "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
                    "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
                    "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
                    "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
                   }]{Neo Euler}
```

#### In PDFLaTeX

This is a popular choice, and you have a number of different packages.  The `eulerpx` package combines symbols and digits from `newpxmath` with letters from Euler.  It’s attractive and still being maintained.  You can also load `newpxtext` or `tgpagella` with `eulervm`. (And possibly `newpxmath` before `eulervm` in case you need any of the additional symbols it defines.)  If you need more math alphabets, such as Euler Script and Euler Fraktur, you can load them through `mathalfa`.  The `classicthesis` package uses Palatino by default and has a `euler` option.