# How to use AMS Euler font in functions such as \sin and \cos?

Tags: fonts, amsmath, computer-modern, eulervm, euler

Looking carefully at a [basic **AMS Euler** example](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AMS_Euler_sample.png), we see that the output of`\sin` and `\cos` macros are rendered using **Computer Modern** font instead of the **AMS Euler** font. So, how to use AMS Euler font in functions such as `\sin` and `\cos`? If possible, please explain why is this the default behaviour?

This is the example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{euler}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\[ AMS\ Euler \]

\[ \int_0^3 9x^2 + 2x + 4\, dx = 3x^3 + x^2 + 4x + C \Big\rbrack_0^3 = 102 \]

\[ e^{x+iy} = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y) \]

\[ x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \]

\end{document}
```

and this is the output:

[image: AMS Euler sample]

Comment: That's wanted: the symbols for functions such as sine, cosine and logarithm are typeset with the normal text font; otherwise `sin` would mean the product of s by i by n.

Comment: @egreg So, maybe chaning the normal font to something like `Palatino` is a good practice? Like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84770/using-palatino-and-euler-math

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Euler is not really compatible with Computer Modern, it's better with Palatino, in my opinion.

As a rule, the operator names such as sine, cosine and logarithm are typeset with the normal (upright) text font, in order not to be confused with products of quantities: “sin” does not mean the product “s by i by n”.

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}

\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\begin{document}

$e^{x+iy} = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)$

\end{document}
```

Note that `eulervm` is to be preferred to the outdated `euler` package.

[image]

You can surely see that the appearance is better.

You can change the font for operator names to be the same as for variables:

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}

\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\operator@font}{\mathgroup\symletters}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$e^{x+iy} = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I recommend not doing it.

Comment: Thanks. But as operator names such as sine, cosine and logarithm should be different from the math font, how can I recognize `Palatino` from `AMS Euler`? They look somehow similar.

Comment: @Ho1 Well, no! They have something in common, but the serifs in Palatino are straight, not curvy.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One additional note: the Wikipedia article says this about `AMS Euler`: "It blends very well with other typefaces made by Hermann Zapf, such as `Palatino`, `Aldus` and `Melior`, but very badly with the default TeX font `Computer Modern`." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMS_Euler